# Colocar chaves primárias em sequência

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, firebird

Tenho a tabela **`empresas`** conforme exemplo:

```
cod | nome
----|----------
3   | Asterix
7   | Lunar
13  | Coimbra
```

Felizmente a tabela de empresas atualmente não tem nenhuma referência em outra tabela, gostaria de poder colocar os números das chaves primárias (coluna **`cod`**) em sequência deixando a tabela conforme abaixo:

```
cod | nome
----|----------
1   | Asterix
2   | Lunar
3   | Coimbra
```

Teria então que fazer um *update* em todos os registros, sei que se eu começar do registro com a chave de menor valor e continuar até a chave de maior valor não terei problema de violação de chave, gostaria de saber se isso é possível.

Inicialmente vou fazer isso num banco de dados [firebird](/questions/tagged/firebird), mas se alguém postar uma resposta em [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) ou [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) terá meu voto.

Comment: Afinal é postgresql, firebird ou MSSQL?

Comment: Se você postar qualquer um desses terá meu voto, a preferência hoje é firebird.

Answer (score 2):

Eis uma solução para SQL Server:

```
-- código #1
with empresas_seq as (
SELECT seq= row_number() over (order by cod), nome
  from bd1..empresas
)
INSERT into bd2..empresas (cod, nome)
  SELECT seq, nome 
    from empresas_seq;
```

---

Para atualizar na tabela atual:

```
-- código #2 v2
USE bd1;

with empresas_seq as (
SELECT cod, seq= row_number() over (order by cod), nome
  from empresas
)
UPDATE empresas_seq
  set cod= seq;
```

Eis outra solução para atualizar, mais tradicional:

```
-- código #3
with empresas_seq as (
SELECT cod, seq= row_number() over (order by cod), nome
  from empresas
)
UPDATE E
  set cod= ES.seq
  from empresas as E
       inner join empresas_seq as ES on ES.cod = E.cod;
```

Comment: Vou testar. (Y)

Comment: Funcionou aqui. Obrigado.